# [java]pre and post increment algorithm

Tags: java

```
 int x=4;
 double y=  841/++x%10/2+15/(x++/3.0);

 System.out.println("y = " + y);
```

why is the answer 13? why is ++x = 6 and x++ = 7??
Thanks a lot. I'm so new to Java.
Isn't it x=4 , ++x=5   x++=6 ? how is it 6 and 7.

Comment: You should be able to crack this puzzle yourself if you arm yourself with Java's operator precedence table. (Note that you expression would be undefined in C and C++).

Comment: The duplicate addresses only part of the puzzle. There are other things in there too: type promotion being one of them.

Comment: i really don't understand how a variable changed from 4 to 6...

Comment: Because that's what ++x and x++ do.

Comment: can you do it to me step by step.. i know its bad but i do beg your help...

Comment: shouldn't it just add by 1?

Comment: It would be better if you read the duplicate carefully.